# How to create a blocking dialog with more than two buttons in dm-script

Tags: dialog, blocking, dm-script

How do I create a dialog that has more than two custom buttons instead of the "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons that blocks the script?

---

One can create a dialog with two custom buttons in [dm-script](/questions/tagged/dm-script) by using `TwoButtonDialog()`. But consider the following example dialog asking whether to overwrite files. This dialog needs more than just the "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons.

[image: Overwrite dialog as an example for a FiveButtonDialog()]

This dialog can simply be created by using the `UIFrame` and dialog functions. But using `UIFrame::display()` does not wait for the user to interact. The dialog will be shown and the script continues. When using `UIFrame::pose()`, this blocks the current script but also always adds the "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons. So using those functions don't seem to fit in this case here.

How do I create a dialog that prevents the script to go on without the additional "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons so I can add my own buttons? And optionally, how do I make this dialog modal?

---

## What I have tried

### Version 1

I tried to block the current working thread by waiting on a `Signal` as shown in the example code below. I am creating the dialog and using `UIFrame::display()` which does not add any buttons. Then I wait for the signal that is set in the button click callback.

```c
number index = -1;
object wait_signal = NewSignal(0);

class ButtonDialog : UIFrame{
    void button_pressed(object self, number i){
        index = i;
        wait_signal.SetSignal();
        self.close();
    }

    object init(object self){
        // creating dialog contents, for full example look at the bottom
        return self;
    }
}    

// Version 1
alloc(ButtonDialog).init().display(title);
wait_signal.waitOnSignal(10, NULL);

result("The index is " + index + "\n");
```

<sup>Executable version at the bottom, uncomment `Version 1` block, comment all other versions</sup>

But this doesn't work. The appearing dialog is not finished and looks like the following:

[image: Empty dm-script dialog]

As soon as I change the window, the dialog shows the text and the buttons but still is not clickable. Plus the layout is not perfect.

### Version 2

So I thought to move the dialog in a separate thread completely. This way it is able to take as long as needed for initializiation and is for sure usable since the new separate thread is never blocked.

```c
number index = -1;
object wait_signal = NewSignal(0);

class ButtonDialog : UIFrame{
    void button_pressed(object self, number i){
        index = i;
        wait_signal.SetSignal();
        self.close();
    }

    object init(object self){
        // creating dialog contents, for full example look at the bottom
        return self;
    }
}

class ButtonDialogThread : Thread{
    object init(object self){
        return self;
    }
    
    void RunThread(object self){
        alloc(ButtonDialog).init().display(title);
    }
}

// Version 2
alloc(ButtonDialogThread).init().startThread();
wait_signal.waitOnSignal(10, NULL);

result("The index is " + index + "\n");
```

<sup>Executable version at the bottom, uncomment `Version 2` block, comment all other versions</sup>

But this results in the same output as the above mentioned and shown dialog.

### Version 3

The even more basic approach was to use a `while` loop with sleeping inbetween. As far as I know `Signal`s work exactly like this. But still I gave it a try.

```c
number index = -1;
object wait_signal = NewSignal(0);

class ButtonDialog : UIFrame{
    void button_pressed(object self, number i){
        index = i;
        wait_signal.SetSignal();
        self.close();
    }

    object init(object self){
        // creating dialog contents, for full example look at the bottom
        return self;
    }
}

// Version 3
alloc(ButtonDialog).init().display(title);
number security_counter = 0;
while(index == -1 && security_counter < 100){
    sleep(0.1);
    security_counter += 1;
}

result("The index is " + index + "\n");
```

<sup>Executable version at the bottom, uncomment `Version 3` block, comment all other versions</sup>

But again, the same result as in `Version 1`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I block the main thread until the shown dialog has some user interaction?

---

```c
string text = "Several files already exist. Do you want to overwrite the file 'test_file.dm4' and 12 others?"
string button0 = "Yes";
string button1 = "Yes, all";
string button2 = "No";
string button3 = "No, all";
string button4 = "Cancel";

string title = "Overwrite?";
object wait_signal = NewSignal(0);
number index = -1;

class ButtonDialog : UIFrame{
    void button_pressed(object self, number i){
        index = i;
        wait_signal.SetSignal();
        self.close();
    }
    
    void button0_pressed(object self){self.button_pressed(0);}
    void button1_pressed(object self){self.button_pressed(1);}
    void button2_pressed(object self){self.button_pressed(2);}
    void button3_pressed(object self){self.button_pressed(3);}
    void button4_pressed(object self){self.button_pressed(4);}
    
    object init(object self){
        TagGroup dlg, dlg_items, wrapper, label, b;
        
        index = -1;
        
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog("Press a button", dlg_items);
        
        dlg_items.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateLabel(text));
        
        wrapper = DLGCreateGroup();
        wrapper.DLGTableLayout(5, 1, 1);
        dlg_items.DLGAddElement(wrapper);
        
        b = DLGCreatePushButton(button0, "button0_pressed");
        b.DLGWidth(80);
        wrapper.DLGAddElement(b);
        
        b = DLGCreatePushButton(button1, "button1_pressed");
        b.DLGWidth(80);
        wrapper.DLGAddElement(b);
        
        b = DLGCreatePushButton(button2, "button2_pressed");
        b.DLGWidth(80);
        wrapper.DLGAddElement(b);
        
        b = DLGCreatePushButton(button3, "button3_pressed");
        b.DLGWidth(80);
        wrapper.DLGAddElement(b);
        
        b = DLGCreatePushButton(button4, "button4_pressed");
        b.DLGWidth(80);
        wrapper.DLGAddElement(b);
        
        self.super.init(dlg);
        return self;
    }
}

class ButtonDialogThread : Thread{
    object init(object self){
        return self;
    }
    
    void RunThread(object self){
        alloc(ButtonDialog).init().display(title);
    }
}       

// Version 1
// alloc(ButtonDialog).init().display(title);
// wait_signal.waitOnSignal(10, NULL);

// Version 2
alloc(ButtonDialogThread).init().startThread();
wait_signal.waitOnSignal(10, NULL);

// Version 3
// alloc(ButtonDialog).init().display(title);
// number security_counter = 0;
// while(index == -1 && security_counter < 100){
//  sleep(0.1);
//  security_counter += 1;
// }

result("The index is " + index + "\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually **all** your attempts are good ones and in principle working. (The first one being the one to go with.) However, they are not working because you are missing one point:

> All UI actions in DigitalMicrograph are run on the main thread of the application.

And also:

> Any script is, by default, run on the main thread of the application.

Thus, your script is self-blocking. The script, after initializing the dialog and sending the message to display it, blocks the main-thread. therefore the messages to properly draw the dialog can not be executed and the dialog is not properly displayed.
However, as the script waits for a message from the dialog, you're in a blocked situation.

You can not *put a dialog on a separate thread* - you can only put the script to *launch* the dialog on a separate thread. The UI will always need some main-thread cycles to actually work.

Thus, what you really need to do is to ensure the script isn't on the main thread.
The simplest thing is to use the *old* method of putting script execution on a separate thread by having the very first line of the script written ***exactly*** as follows:

```c
// $BACKGROUND$
```

(All capitalized and a white space after the `//` )
If you add this little line to your script, all is working.
A more elegant way of starting a script on a separate thread is to use the threading class as you did in **version 2**. Just makes sure you put the script *waiting for the signal* on the background thread, not the dialog.

Comment: Aha, that is why it doesn't work. Perfect explanation plus a working solution. Thank you